# Laravel test returns 404

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-8

I'm trying to run some tests but it is returning 404 after the first run. Sometimes it runs normally, but 90% of the time, it returns me a 404 response.

Pstoman request works 100% of the time.

First time running (the failure here is from another test):

[image: 1First run]

Next times (now I'm getting the 404):

[image: Next runs]

Here is my `phpunit.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <coverage processUncoveredFiles="true">
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </include>
    </coverage>
    <php>
        <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <server name="APP_URL" value="http://localhost"/>
        <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
        <server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
        <server name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
        <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

The test:

```
public function verify_username_should_return_id_when_existing_document()
{
    $this->seed(UserTypeSeeder::class);
    $user = User::factory()->create();

    $response = $this->withHeaders([
        'user_type' => $user->type->id,
    ])->postJson("api/auth/username", [
        "username" => $user->document
    ]);

    $response->assertOk()
        ->assertJson(["id" => 1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that for some reason if I change the `$this->withHeaders(['user_type' => $user->type->id,])` to `$this->withHeader("user_type", $user->type->id)` it works but it doesn't make sense to me